# how to hide url in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

I m doing web application in cakephp1.3. I want my Url

http://mydomine.com/cakephp/users/login to be display as http://mydomine.com/users/login.
Where users is controller name and login is action. I dont want to display cakephp on my url. Please help me to fix this bug.

Thanks in advance

Pushpa

Comment: pushpa, you might be interested in CakePHPs routing capabilities, documented [here.](http://book.cakephp.org/#!/view/945/Routes-Configuration) And for a proper setup look [here](http://ad7six.com/2007/08/24/Production-setup-revisited.html).

Comment: I added a second link for you.

Comment: thanks benjamin, I tried with routing configuration in routes.php, there i can hide only controller or action name but not cakephp root directory, can u guide me how to hide my cakephp(root) folder

Comment: the second link I added is a superb explanation of how to lay out your folder structure. You can use it to achieve your results. Yours

Answer (score 1):

You can direct your domain to the cakephp directory... No need to work with rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

either move all the files from the cakephp folder to the / folder, 
or use apache rewrite rules to remove cakephp from the request

Comment: Thanks sharpner, can you guide me how to do apache rewrite ?

Comment: To clarify sharpners point move all the files folders in /cakephp/ back to the webroot. You don't need the cakephp directory

Answer (score 0):

Put all of the content of your app dir to your web folder and then u will be able to access home page of your project directly. Don't forget to copy .htaccess.